# question about readwrite properties

Tags: cocoa

One thing that I like about readwrite properties is that you get KVO compliance 'for free', so I tend to use it on properties even when they are only written to from within the object to which the property belongs.  On the other hand, I understand that a property should only be set to readwrite if it is intended to be writeable by other objects.  So, should I use readwrite even though I only call the setter from self:

```
[self setFoo:bar];
```

The alternative (I think) is to use:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"foo"];
foo = bar;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"foo"];
```

which is an extra two lines I code I have to write every time I want to change foo.  Which is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a property `readonly` in the public interface, then promote it to `readwrite` in a class extension in the implementation file.

Foo.h:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
@property (readonly) NSString *frob;
@end
```

Foo.m:

```
@interface Foo ()
@property (readwrite) NSString *frob;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize frob;

// Methods in Foo.m can now use foo.frob = @"whatever";
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

in .h

```
   @property(nonatomic,readwrite,retain)NSString *foo;
```

then

in .m

```
  @synthesize foo;
```

then use anywhere like

```
  self.foo=@"madhu";
```

or

```
  self.foo=@"mike";
```

but if u synthesized like above then u have to use always like

self with dot

everytime while change the string

```
   it will automatically release the older object then retain the new one.so no pain to take care of old one for release and no pain for retain the new one.
```

i think its better